# Handling heterogenous data and large 'binary' data

Tags: pandas

Here is my use-case (which I think is fairly typical):

I have a bunch of heterogeneous data which can be easily cast in the form of a table. Depending on conditions applied to one or more columns I select various rows. Call this the select_table

I also have a bunch of binary data that is associated with some of the columns.

I want to efficiently pull up this binary data based on conditions applied to my select_table and easily maintain the link between row and column in the select_table.

Ideally I would like a frame_table that accepts binary (object) data that allows me to pull up the binary data transparently with my select_table (just as I would do with regular data types). However, I can not save data frames with object columns as frame_tables.

Right now I have two pandas data frames. One is select_table and the other stores the binary data as objects in the appropriate columns. This forces me to load the whole binary data table into memory at once and then select based on the row identity returned from the select_table.

I have taken to saving the binary table in a separate hdf5 file and using row indexes from my select_table to pull off the required chunk of data from disk.

My question: Is there a proper way to handle this use case in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a very similar use case to [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3032). near the end is a script I wrote to store both the main data and the binary data in HDF5 and wrap them in objects, so that you can have 'automatic' sub-queries (e.g. you do you main query then sub-query for the attached data)

Another way to approach this is to store a reference in your select_table file to the binary data, which could be a `url-like`, maybe a file and node reference to another file, e.g.
something like `/path_to_my_data_file/file.hdf:/node_path_in_hdf5_file`